# Powershell Loop through list of computer and count files, in network share folder

Tags: powershell

One liner works fine from my server to a remote computer. I want to take my one liner and convert it to a ForEach loop. I want to loop through all the computers in my environment.

One liner:

```
Write-output (Get-ChildItem '\\mycomputer\C$\Program Files\OSC\LogGen\LOGS').Count
```

ForEach attempt (not working) foreach loop through list of computers and return count results for each computer in list.

```
$computerlist = gc "D:\computerlist.txt"

ForEach ($host in $computerlist) { 
Write-Output (Get-ChildItem "\\$host\C$\Program Files\LOGS").Count
}
```

Comment: *not working* is an absolutely useless problem description. In what way does it *not work*? Do you get the wrong results? Do you get an error? If so, what is the **exact** error message you're getting? You alone know what *not working* means, and if you want someone here to help you you need to share that information. We can't read your mind or see your screen from here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try look in to ps drives, They are really neat and i use them everywhere now.

```
New-PSDrive -Name U -PSProvider FileSystem -Root "\\$PC\C$"
```

This will create a new drive called `U:` that you can interact with just like a network drive. The main difference is this drive only exists in the scope of the script. When creating drives in a loop its inportant to close the drive to free up the letter for the next iteration.

```
ForEach ($PC in $computerlist) { 
    New-PSDrive -Name U -PSProvider FileSystem -Root "\\$PC\C$"
    Write-Output (Get-ChildItem "U:\Program Files\LOGS").Count
    Remove-PSDrive U -force
}
```

Comment: Had to to change $host to $var I was getting an error, Host is a restricted variable.